# System call is blocking (program wont end) while creating a new process

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to use the clone system call and sometimes the program won't end. This program just creates a new process using clone and tries to execute the cat command. Here is the program:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int childFunc(void*arg)
{
   char* paramlist[] = {"/bin/cat", "test.txt", NULL};
   execv("/bin/cat",paramlist);
   _exit(1);
}

int main(void) {
  int STACKSIZE = 65536;
  void* stack;
  stack = malloc(STACKSIZE);
  
  int ret = clone(childFunc, stack + STACKSIZE, 0, NULL);

  waitpid(ret, NULL, 0);
  free(stack);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a new process or a new thread? If a new process, why aren't you just using `fork`? If a new thread, what do you expect the `exec` family of functions to do in a multithreaded program?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica its a requirement for me to use clone instead of fork but yes i want to create a new process.

Comment: When you've ran the program and you think it isn't ending, what happens when you press Enter?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica yea it does terminate why is this happening?

Comment: `clone`  is not the same as `fork`.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `clone` to create a new process that you later `wait` on, you need to either pass `SIGCHLD` in `flags` to `clone` (recommended, unless you want to change what signal gets sent on purpose) or pass `__WALL` or `__WCLONE` in `options` to `waitpid`. See [`man 2 clone`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) and [`man 2 waitpid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) for more details. Since you weren't doing this, the `waitpid` syscall was failing due to not having anything to wait on instead of waiting for the child process to complete. This resulted in the contents of `test.txt` being printed after your shell prompt, which made you think it was still running, even though it wasn't. You would have noticed this if you checked the result `waitpid` returned.